# Ruby how to check if hash has a key that is a variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Ruby hash that has attributes like this:

```
{:type=>"article", :id=>"207", :infographic=>nil, :guest_post=>nil, :interview=>nil}
```

Suppose I want to check if this hash has a key that is the same as a variable "keyVar"

```
keyVar = ":type"
```

If I do `hash.has_key?(keyVar)`, it returns false, but it obviously does have the key.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `keyVar = ":type"`  this not symbol `:"type"` this symbol

Comment: Write this `keyVar = "type"`, then `has_key?(keyVar.to_sym)`.

Comment: If you will be changing the value of `key_var`, you may as well change it to the key you are looking for (here a symbol): 
`key_var = :type; hash.has_key?(key_var) # => true`.  I changed the name of your variable to conform with Ruby's [naming conventions](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_names.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your `keyVar` variable is a string, not a symbol. Worse yet, it's a string with a prefixed colon, so it's not easily possible to convert it to a symbol.

What you want is

```
hash.has_key?(:type)
```

But what you're doing is:

```
hash.has_key?(":type")
```

Simpy using `":type".to_sym` would get you `:":type"`. You'll need something like this:

```
hash.has_key?(keyVar.gsub(":", "").to_sym)
```

Comment: Hello!! There is no method called `has_key`, rather `has_key?`.. Change it

Comment: Sorry. Fixed my typo.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking for the wrong key. Do this:

```
key_var = :type
hash.key?(key_var)
```

---

If you happened to have the wrong key:

```
key_var = ":type"
```

then, the way to convert that to the correct key is:

```
key_var.delete(":").to_sym
```

so

```
hash.has_key?(key_var.delete(":").to_sym)
```

will work. Using `gsub` as another answer suggests is meaningless as there is only one `:` in the string. `sub` is better, but why use it when you can use `delete`?

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to check

```
> hash = {:type=>"article",
          :id=>"207",
          :infographic=>nil, 
          :guest_post=>nil, 
          :interview=>nil}

> hash.keys.include?(:type)
> true
> hash.has_key?(:type)
> true
> hash.key?(:type)
> true
```

and more.... Just read [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html)